# What equivalent in Delphi of pre-increment (++i) in C++ For command?

Tags: for-loop, delphi, pre-increment

Wha's equivalent in Delphi of this c++ sintaxe?

> See that **i** variable is incremented before.

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

In my case, this is how **++i** is used with sintaxe above:

```cpp
void testStruct *testMethod()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
   {
      if(values[i].id == (DWORD) 10)
          return &values[i];
   }

   return NULL;
}
```

Comment: In Delphi you cannot manually alter the value of the counter. What's the purpose of this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
```

The pre-increment vs post-increment is not relevant here. Semantically this is just the same as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

In Delphi this would be

```
for i := 0 to 19 do
```

Pre-increment matters in expressions where the value of the variable is used. For instance

```
x[++i] = 42;
```

differs from

```
x[i++] = 42;
```

because the value of `++i` differs from the value of `i++`. However in your C++ for loop, the pre-increment operator is used solely to increment the loop variable, and the value of the expression is not used.

Just to make this clear, if `i` is `0` then `++i == 1` and `i++ == 0`. But in the C++ loop, the value of the increment expression is not used, and the only point of it is the side effect of the increment.

Comment: Then based in your answer, **++i** is the same that **i++** on C++, right? Are only two options that will produce the same finalresult.

Comment: No. They are not the same in general. But they are the same in this context.

Comment: @BrowJr: In the for loop construct, it doesn't matter whether you use `i++` or `++i`, because the *result* of the expression is not used, only the (side-)effect that `i` is incremented. In other contexts, where the *result of the expression* matters, like the one David added, it can make a difference.

Comment: And for those Delphi doesn't really have equivalents, if only to prevent confusion. There is the `Inc` procedure, but it doesn't return a value, so it cannot be used as an expression. It would be easy to write PreInc and PostInc functions that do, but, well, meh...